# How to fix messed up GUI when Installing Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, graphics, gui, preinstallation

I tried downloading the 32 bit version of Ubuntu 13.04, and when it finished, I used the universal USB installer tool, provided on the ubuntu website. That was all successful, but when I tried to boot it, the GUI was completely messed up. It loaded the system itself, but once it went into the desktop with the dialog prompting for a language for installation, the screen went whacko. Every other Horizontal line of pixels was messed up, and it had columns (kind of) that repeated what the screen should look like, but only a small region of it.

My Processor is AMD 64 bit, so I tried again with the 64 bit version of Ubuntu, but the exact same thing happened. (By the way, I have slow internet, so each download took about 4-5 hours, along with several failed downloads.) I tried the same thing using a different usb mounting software, but the same GUI issue happened. Each time I retried, I completely wiped and re-formatted the USB disk. Nothing is working. What should I do? Should I download the Windows Installer? Use a CD? Please help! Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From your description this sounds like a graphics card issue. The boot menu where you select the language would be 'grub' which is a software that Ubuntu uses to boot into the main OS. (Grub v2.something to be more specific)
Grub loads using the Linux VESA driver, which is compatible with a very wide range of graphics cards. 
But I suppose it is possible that it's not compatible with yours.
If that's the case, then the best thing to do would be to get Ubuntu to boot off the USB stick into the "Live session".
The live session is when Linux boots pre-install. It will at that point load the open source drivers for your graphics card. Which hopefully will work better than the VESA drivers... Quite likely not though, but it's worth a shot.

Normally, if you don't press a key as the Ubuntu USB stick boots, it would automatically select English as the default language and boot into the live session.
Or if that's not the case (some of the USB stick creators put on their own grub menus), then you can see if it's possible to navigate the grub menu to select your language and then select "try ubuntu without installing" or some such, which is the default boot mode and will boot a live session.

It might also help to search the model of your graphics card/ chip and see if other Linux users have been having the same issue, and what their solutions were.

Comment: The problem is, it did go into the pre-installation live session thing, but the graphics were so messed up that it only showed a small portion of the screen. Where the cursor clicked and what the screen showed were two completely different things. But anyway, I tried the windows installer for version 12.04 LTS and the same thing happened. But when I plugged in a second display, it was slightly better. There are still a ton of graphics isssues, but it's usable. My graphics card is really old and pretty crappy (about 5-6 years old) and is not detected by the system. How can I update the driver?